# How does Bezout's Theorem hold in a Projective Plane where Origin ($\mathcal{O}$) is not $(0,1,0)$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space

In my class on Elliptic Curves, we showed that in a Projective Plane a line intersects an elliptic curve at exactly 3 points including point at infinity (with multiplicities) satisfying Bezout's Theorem.

But the point at infinity, $\mathcal{O}$, does not need to be $(0,1,0)$. It can be any point $(x,y,z)$ such that $z=0$.

So, now if I have a line intersecting 3 points of the curve (say $P,Q,R$), I can let my $\mathcal{O}$ be in the direction of the line segment $\overline{PR}$ and then the full line will intersect the curve at a $4^{\text{th}}$ point, which is $\mathcal{O}$ but this should not be possible as per Bezout's Theorem.

So, how does Bezout's Theorem hold when $\mathcal{O} \neq (0,1,0)$?

Comment: $\mathcal O$ still needs to be a point on your elliptic curve! So you can't just choose it to be a random point in projective space.

Comment: @Mathmo123, why is this fixed $\mathcal{O}$ always on the curve then? And why would a different one not work? I don’t understand

Comment: The *definition* of an elliptic curve is a smooth, projective genus 1 curve with a marked point, $\mathcal O$. You can already see the problem in your formulation. If you choose a random $\mathcal O$, then the segment $\overline{PR}$ will intersect the curve in three places, and it will go through "$\mathcal O$", but since this $\mathcal O$ is not actually on the curve, there is no contradiction to Bezout.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you for the explanation, that makes sense. I was initially told that $\mathcal{O}$ can be any arbitrary point (as long as $z=0$) but the instructor corrected that after your comment.